# When I make the audio and video sync in gstreamer, there would be a huge delay

Tags: gstreamer, audio-video-sync

I use the gstreamer to decode the H264, when I use the pipeline like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0  udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0:15550 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)33,encoding-name=(string)MP2T"  ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin latency=800 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux name=demux demux.  ! h264parse ! queue  ! omxh264dec ! vspfilter ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=480 ! waylandsink sync=false max-lateness=-1  demux. !  aacparse ! queue max-size-buffers=8192000 max-size-time=2000000000 ! faad ! alsasink device=media
```

there would be only about 200ms delay.

And when I set the `sync=true`, like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0  udpsrc uri=udp://0.0.0.0:15550 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)33,encoding-name=(string)MP2T"  ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin latency=800 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux name=demux demux.  ! h264parse ! queue  ! omxh264dec ! vspfilter ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=480 ! waylandsink sync=true max-lateness=-1  demux. !  aacparse ! queue max-size-buffers=8192000 max-size-time=2000000000 ! faad ! alsasink device=media
```

the dalay would reach 1200ms

I have no idea about it.